# Why task "promote this server to a domain controller" shows despite the server being already added to a domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

In Windows Server 2019 / server manager, a warning shows:

> post-deployment configuration / configuration required for ADDS at server_name / promote this server to a domain controller

[image]

I already added `server_name` to the domain, my domain controller server (DC) is also my DNS, and I added its address to `server_name`; I installed `ad-domain-services` so I can manage users and computers of the domain from `server_name`.

Why the warning shows ? How to deactivate it (it is persistent) ?

Comment: It looks as though you asked it to install the Active Directory Domain Services role?  If you've changed your mind about wanting the machine to be a domain controller, remove the role.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I did it all from powershell. The role was added, I believe after adding the ADDS tools. So I should not have added the ADDS, but went through a ps-session to the DC to manage everything.

Comment: OK.  So you were able to add the tools, but you accidentally added the role as well?  Hopefully it will just be a matter of removing the role to get rid of the alert about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've joined the server to the domain but you haven't made the server a Domain Controller for the domain. Adding the AD DS Role does not make the server a Domain Controller for the domain. If you do not intend for the server to be a Domain Controller for the domain then remove the AD DS role.

If you only want to manage the domain from the server then you only need to add the AD DS Role Administration Tools.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens if you finish the DC promo using the command line instead of the Wizard. Just hit Promote the Server to a Domain Controller and then cancel the rest. The warning will disappear once it knows the promotion has finished.